# Service not restart after swiped out from recent list in xiaomi

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, xiaomi

I have a service started from Manifest, the service is running fine when it starts for the first time. It is showing 2 running app - 1 process and 1 service. but when I swipe out my app from recent task list it doesn't auto-start my service again on xiaomi devices. It successfully auto starts in other devices like Lenovo.

Here is my service class :-

```
public class StickyService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "StickyService";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        startReceiver();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startMyOwnForeground();
        } else {
            startForeground(1, new Notification());
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void startMyOwnForeground() {
        startTimer();
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "e xample.permanence";
        String channelName = "Background Service";
        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
        chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert manager != null;
        manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                .setContentTitle("App is running in background")
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .build();
        startForeground(2, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onUnbind");
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");

        sendBroadcast(new Intent("GET_BUZZER"));

        //create an intent that you want to start again.
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StickyService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 2000, pendingIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onTaskRemoved");

        sendBroadcast(new Intent("GET_BUZZER"));

        //create an intent that you want to start again.
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StickyService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 2000, pendingIntent);

        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }

    private void startReceiver() {
        RestartReceiver receiver = new RestartReceiver();
        IntentFilter localIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        localIntentFilter.addAction("GET_BUZZER");
        registerReceiver(receiver, localIntentFilter);
        startService(new Intent(this, StickyService.class));
    }

    public class RestartReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Inside receiver inline class");

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, StickyService.class);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                context.startForegroundService(myIntent);
            } else {
                context.startService(myIntent);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I am registering my broadcast receiver in java code (not in manifest). I used a service class to register broadcast receiver.

Manifest :-

```
<service
    android:name=".ForceCloseAutoStart.StickyService"
    android:process=":StickyService" />
```

I also make below changes in xiaomi device :- `Settings->Battery->Manage Apps Battery Usage` Still not working.

Please help with any solution which work on this devices.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to enable Autostart service in your Xiaomi device.

1. Open the Security menu on your Xiaomi device.
2. Tap Permissions.
3. Tap Autostart.
4. Swipe to enable Autostart for your app.

Check here:- http://nine-faq.9folders.com/articles/8772-how-to-manage-autostart-service-on-the-xiaomi-devices